# Why is visual studio running code analysis every time I start debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

I start debugging, run through some breakpoints, stop debugging, and then start it again. No code changes are made. Each time, visual studio appears to rebuild the solution and re-run code analysis despite not making any code changes.

I suspect this because it switches focus to the code analysis window, clears the current analysis, displays 'Building...' for a little while, and then repopulates the code analysis window.

I've checked each project's 'Code Analysis' tab in the properties window and none of them have 'Enable Code Analysis' checked (I had to uncheck it from one of them). Why is it doing this? How do I make it stop?

Comment: Did you consider using some other compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) perhaps on some other operating system (e.g. some Linux distribution)?

Comment: VS compiles again if it's timestamps are screwed up (Some part gets cached). If you can somehow refresh the cache (clean build or delete some related files), you might get back on track. @Basile: switch OS on a an issue? Dude!

Comment: I'm biased toward Linux (using Unix since 1987, and Linux since 1994) and never coded on Windows, but as a development platform, Linux is worth trying (with fresh eyes).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I also prefer Linux and also think suggesting an OS, compiler, and IDE switch over an inconvenience is a little extreme. However, if this were a personal project rather than a massive solution from work, I would still consider it :)

Comment: This is why I commented, and did not answer